# How to make a binary pandas matrix with words in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a dataframe with a column that contains a list on every row:

```
df['list1'][0] = ['a','b','c','d']

df['list1'][1] = [,'b','c','d', 'e']
```

Now I want to make a binary matrix from this, with the letters as column names and a 1 if the list on that row contains the letter and if not a 0. I can't find a solution for this. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) if performance is important:
:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list1':[ ['a','b','c','d'], ['b','c','d', 'e']]})
print (df)
          list1
0  [a, b, c, d]
1  [b, c, d, e]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['list1']),columns=mlb.classes_)
```

Or [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['list1'].values.tolist()), prefix_sep='', prefix='')
         .max(level=0, axis=1))
```

Another solution, but slow if large data is use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df1 = df['list1'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

---

```
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1  1
```

EDIT: If need original columns with removed `list1` column use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list1':[ ['a','b','c','d'], ['b','c','d', 'e']],
                   'col1':[1,2],
                   'col2':list('XY')})
print (df)
          list1  col1 col2
0  [a, b, c, d]     1    X
1  [b, c, d, e]     2    Y

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('list1')),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1  1
```

---

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('list1').values.tolist()), prefix_sep='', prefix='')
         .max(level=0, axis=1))
```

---

```
df1 = df.pop('list1').str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

---

```
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   col1 col2  a  b  c  d  e
0     1    X  1  1  1  1  0
1     2    Y  0  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately now i lose the other data of the dataframe: df['name'] and df['title]. is there a way to make df['list1'] a binary matrix with df['name'] and df['title] still in the dataframe?

Comment: @Jan - Can you change my data `df = pd.DataFrame({'list1':[ ['a','b','c','d'], ['b','c','d', 'e']]})` with another columns with expected output?

Comment: I mean that in this way i lose the data from other columns in the dataframe

Comment: @Jan - give em a sec.

Comment: @Jan - Do you need remove original `list1` column?

Comment: yes that one can be removed. I am trying to get a df with the columns: name, title and all the letters